# Calculated column for number of blanks in a related column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table in powerBI called "Table1" with X number of columns (Col1, Col2, Col3...Coln). I am trying to calculate the number of blanks each column has in a separate table. Using PowerQuery, I have created a second table, "Table2", that has the column names from Table1 as a column called "Column_Name".

In Table2, I am trying to calculate the number of blanks each column has in Table1 by creating a calculated column. This is my DAX so far:

No_of_blanks = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table1'), FILTER('Table1', ISBLANK('Table2'[Column_Name])))

However, I just get a blank column as a result, and I believe I am close but I am probably missing something. I have also tried the DAX with RELATEDTABLE but I get the same result.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not possible to refer to columns dynamically in DAX. Your `No_of_blanks` will need to have a `SWITCH` statement to switch on the column name string, and then manually target that column. Since you're creating Table2 in PowerQuery, I suggest you add this column in PowerQuery as well.

Comment: @SamNseir I totally agree with you and I believe that DAX/PQ are meant for real analysis use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I started by creating a table to contain the names of the columns in Power Query like following :

1. I created a reference of the original table :
   [image]
2. Unpivoted the columns :

[image]

3. Removed the other columns and kept only the one with the column names :
   [image]

4.Finally, I removed the duplicates :

[image]

Now, jumping to DAX, I created for each count of blank values in a specific column a measure :

```
CountBlankColA = COUNTBLANK(MyTable[ColA])

CountBlankColA = COUNTBLANK(MyTable[ColA])

CountBlankColA = COUNTBLANK(MyTable[ColA])
```

and then :

```
Measure_Column_Blanks = SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    SELECTEDVALUE(ColumnNames[Attribute]) = "ColA", [CountBlankColA],
    SELECTEDVALUE(ColumnNames[Attribute]) = "ColB", [CountBlankColB],
    SELECTEDVALUE(ColumnNames[Attribute]) = "ColC", [CountBlankColC],
    // Repeat for each column...
    BLANK() // Return blank or a default value if no match is found
)
```

Output :

[image]

[Link to the pbix file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b74e88308bfe8ee034d5ebbf688167d220240207125615/a3a9fe)

Comment: Or you could, select all the columns and do a replace value to replace `null` with `-99999`. Then unpivot as you have, then filer on `-99999`. Finally, do a `Group by` with `Count` `Count rows`. No need for DAX.

Comment: I am just following what the OP wants.

Comment: Opps, sorry, I mistook you for the OP, my bad.